# Windows App crashing on clicking a tile

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have made a few windows basic apps that give information on specific things...but the apps are crashing when a tile is clicked. the exception seems to be in InfoHub.exe

I have used Windows default Win8AppMaker to create the apps. i.e. I have filled data in excel file and it has automatically generated the code that I have used..

can anyone please let me know why my apps are crashing

Comment: What is specifically the error/exception that you are getting.

Comment: 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'pubads'

Comment: you're creating an app off of a code generator, so we'd need to know more about how that generator is implemented. You'll probably have to debug through the code it produces, unless "pubads" is something that's meaningful to you (e.g., you provided in the Excel file). FWIW, looks like that WinAppMaker project is no longer available, so not sure if someone will be able to recreate the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ads for the windows apps were corrupted and crashing the app...I went back to them and let them know of it and my app seemed to work fine, and It got submitted to app store..
Thanks